# Using a class to store information and calling that to build an array

Tags: java, arrays

So here is my questions. I am working on building an array using a defined class. The class looks like below:

```
 class InventoryItem {

    String ItemName;
    int ItemNumber;
    int InStock;
    double UnitPrice;
    double InventoryValue;

    public InventoryItem(String ItemName, int ItemNumber, int InStock, double UnitPrice) {
        this.ItemName = ItemName;
        this.ItemNumber = ItemNumber;
        this.InStock = InStock;
        this.UnitPrice = UnitPrice;
        this.InventoryValue = UnitPrice * InStock;

    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.println("Item Name = " + ItemName);
        System.out.println("Item Number = " + ItemNumber);
        System.out.println("In Stock = " + InStock);
        System.out.println("Item Price = $" + UnitPrice);
        System.out.println("Item value of stocked items = $" + InventoryValue);

    }
}
```

This works just fine when I load it with a test example.

However when I try to build the array using this class something breaks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the inventory program\n")
        System.out.println("This will help keep track of your inventory of office supplies");

        InventoryItem[] Stock;
        InventoryItem[10] = Stock;
        Stock[1] = new InventoryItem("Test", 123456, 500, .99);
        System.out.println("Please enter the Item Nmae");
        ItemName = user_input.nextline();
```

the problem I am having is that it doesn't like the `InventoryItem[] Stock;` It keeps telling me that it cannot find `InventoryItem`. I thought that I could use this class as the array basically. I think that I am asking the right questions, but I am new to this so please bear with me. BTW this test example does not work. However this is the initial test example.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   InventoryItem Stock = new InventoryItem("TEST", 123456789, 999, 1.25);
    Stock.output();
```

Which works fine to load that one line, but I am working towards having the user input each section of the array in order to load it up. Does that make sense or do I just sound like an idiot? I am not great with the terminology, but I am working on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it can't find `InventoryItem`, it may be that `InventoryItem` is in the wrong directory, or needs to be imported. So where is the `InventoryItem` file? Also, it's good practice to make your classes `public`, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I might also point out that `.nextline();` is not a `Scanner` method, but `.nextLine()` is (in `ItemName = user_input.nextline();`). Also, `ItemName` has not been declared yet, so you might want to change that to `String ItemName = ...` unless you've declared it somewhere else. Otherwise, the program doesn't know what `ItemName` is, and it's not known that it is a variable and is going to store a `String`. You also seem to be missing a semicolon at the end of the "Welcome" message on line 3 of `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InventoryItem[] Stock;
InventoryItem[10] = Stock;
```

Should be

```
InventoryItem[] Stock = new InventoryItem[10];
```

Also, I see you doing this (which probably doesn't cause a problem, but just an FYI in case you don't know.

```
 Stock[1] = new InventoryItem("Test", 123456, 500, .99);
```

Arrays' indices are zero-based, meaning that start at 0. So if you're trying to access the first index with the code above, you're actually accessing the second index.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new` to allocate space for your Stock array of InventoryItem

```
InventoryItem[] Stock = new InventoryItem[10];
```

Also, I notice you are using array index 1 to add something to your Stock:

`Stock[1] = new InventoryItem("Test", 123456, 500, .99);`

This is fine, but if you want it to be in the first position, know that Java arrays are zero based.

See [Oracle's tutorial on Java arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of brackets:

```
ArrayList<InventoryItem> Stock = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
```

adding items:

```
Stock.add(new InventoryItem(/*parameters*/);
```

You can find the rest of the methods you can use [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)